# Running Quartz.NET for a specific job every 8 hours starting from 07:00 AM

Tags: c#, cron, quartz.net

Till today I've used Quartz.Net to run cron jobs, for example, every 5 minutes and so on. now I've been asked to run a specific job every 8 hours starting from 07:00 AM. This means that there'll be 3 execution daily, one at 07:00 AM, one at 03:00 PM, and last at 11:PM.

The stupid and simplest way would be to start the app at 07:00 AM and set the cron expression to run every 8 hours. Is there a better way?

My snippet of code is the following

```
   var timespanRecurringJob = configuration.GetValue<TimeSpan>("GSpedService:batchIntervalTracking");

                    logger.LogInformation($"BatchProcessorService starting with interval  {timespanRecurringJob}");

                    IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<TrackingUrlRecurringJob>()
                        .WithIdentity("trackingUrlRecurringJob", "group3") // name "myJob", group "group1"
                        .Build();

                    // Trigger the job to run now, and then every 40 seconds
                    ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                        .WithIdentity("triggerTracking", "group3")
                        .StartNow()
                        .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                            .WithInterval(timespanRecurringJob)
                            .RepeatForever())
                        .Build();

                    // Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
                    await Scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger, cancellationToken);
```

I would have that information somehow in my appsettings.json and not hardcoded in the sources

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This cron will execute your job on required hours, without having to worry about first execution time

```
.WithCronSchedule("0 1 7,15,23 * * ?")
```

Value can be taken from appsettings.json with [IConfiguration.GetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#getvalue)